# I want to ignore a file from git local repository so i have added .gitignore and .swp file inside but still file showing in the "git status"

Tags: git, gitignore

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-100-164:/etc/ansible/roles$ cat .gitignore
# These are some examples of commonly ignored file patterns.
# You should customize this list as applicable to your project.
# Learn more about .gitignore:
#     https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore
*.swp
*xcore/vars/.main.yml.swp
```

```
git status 
    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   argo_setup.yml
    modified:   xcore/tasks/argocd_apps.yml
    deleted:    xcore/vars/.main.yml.swp
    modified:   xcore/vars/main.yml
```

I want to ignore above file please help me!

Comment: Gitignore has no effect on files you yourself have not ignored.

Comment: i'm not getting what you are saying..!!

Comment: I’m saying _you_ committed this file. So gitignore is irrelevant until _you_ remove the file from the next commit. `git rm --cached` the file.

Comment: I have not committed yet

Comment: git status

modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   argo_setup.yml
        modified:   xcore/tasks/argocd_apps.yml
        modified:   xcore/vars/.main.yml.swp
        modified:   xcore/vars/main.yml

Comment: git add . also I have not did as for now. So now I want ignore .swp file before commit

Answer (score 1):

```
deleted:    xcore/vars/.main.yml.swp
```

That means it was tracked, and is staged for deletion in the next commit

Try instead:

```
git reset xcore/vars/.main.yml.swp
git rm --cached xcore/vars/.main.yml.swp
```

Then check if it is ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- xcore/vars/.main.yml.swp
```